# How to change the "Fullscreen in browser" for the Snapped view (Windows 8 apps - Construct 2)

Tags: windows-8, winjs, construct-2

I'm working on a **Windows 8 application** using **Construct 2**.

I set the `Fullscreen in browser` to `Letterbox scale`, and I want to change it to `Scale` for the Snaped view.

I found the `Windows8 on view state Snapped` event, but I didn't found the action that change the `Fullscreen in browser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

First I export the windows 8 application from construct 2 without minifying the script (uncheck Minify script), and then under VS2012 I added to the end of `c2runtime.js` this lines:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
function onResize() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

and I changed the line **18068**, that contains the mode number to :

```
(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value)?2:3
```

Which means when the state view change, I set the **Fullscreen in browser** to `2` or `3` depending on `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value`

*PS : 0 = off, 1 = crop, 2 = scale, 3 = letterbox scale, 4 = integer letterbox scale*

The last part of the `c2runtime.js` :

```
    "media/",
    false,
    768,
    1366,
    (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value)?2:3,
    true,
    true,
    true,
    "1.0",
    2,
    false,
    0,
    false
];
};

window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
function onResize() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```